# save the uploaded .doc file to db with html format

Tags: asp.net, html, doc

In my application,user can upload some doc files to the server,and I want user who do not install ms office can read these documents,so I want to convert the .doc to html and then save the html(binary stream) to oracle db.

I wonder if there is a best pratice to implement this?

Someone tell me to use the com object provoided by the office assembly,it seems that it will transfer the .doc file to a .html file,so I have to save the .html file to db and delete the temp .html file,I want to know if I can save it in db directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to give everyone a bit more information...

I assume you're using a server side technology? Which one?

What database are you using?

The chances are if the COM object is writing it to a file, you will - like you say, just need to copy that into the DB, and delete the temp file.

IMHO - There should be nothing wrong with saving to temp file and outputting that to DB (if you could save to memory that would be even better!)